# Compile time too long (:app:transformJackWithJackForDevDebug)

Tags: android, performance

While compiling I notice since quite a while that compilation time seems pretty slow. 
A little change of code, like adding a comment, and I have generally 1mn15s of compile time just for this little change.

There isn't any module or other projects loaded.

I'm using:

- JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
- build tools 2.2.0-rc1
- gradle 3.0

Notable libraries:

- Retrofit2
- Moshi
- Okhttp3
- Picasso
- Firebase (messaging and crash)
- Mixpanel and Facebook SDK.

**The longest part of the compile time is :app:transformJackWithJackForDevDebug**

Could it be related to the code generated at compile-time by Retrofit/Moshi ? Why a simple comment should put so many heavy things in motion ?

Comment: May be the *internet connection* causes that issue.

Comment: Hello Jaydroider and thank you for your answer.
Though I doubt about it, i'm using a stable 500 mb/s connection.
I don't think the transform task is related to any network call.